# Netplan- How to configure a static IPv6-address and SLACC

Tags: ipv6, static-ip, netplan, dynamic-ip, dhcpv6

I’m facing a situation where I need to configure an interface with both a private static IPv6 address and SLAAC (Stateless Address Autoconfiguration) addresses. The reason behind this requirement is that my public IPv6 network undergoes changes, and I want the interface to obtain SLAAC addresses dynamically while also having a fixed private IPv6 address.

Is it possible to achieve this dual configuration using Netplan, and if so, how can I set it up?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your business account should have a fixed IPv6 delegation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible. You should edit the netpplan configuration file `(etc/netplan/config.yaml)` and here is a example to achieve your goal.

```
  dhcp4: no
  dhcp6: no
  addresses:
    - "YOUR_IPV6"
  accept-ra: yes
```

Comment: This  solution doesn't work.

Comment: I think you would need to set dhcp6 to yes, but some additional info about how it doesn't work would be useful